Blonde Explorer Lady
I saw this on network TV (non-cable), on a Saturday or Sunday afternoon in the mid 1980s, in metro Detroit, USA. It was in color, live action, English language. I don't know whether it was a movie or an episode of a TV show. 
There was a blonde woman and her male companion(s), explorers or something. They came upon a tribe of savages, who had a massive gold statue that looked just like the woman. When they saw the woman, they worshiped her like a goddess, and made her their queen or something. So she was living it up. But what she didn't know was that a little while later, when the stars/planets aligned, they planned to sacrifice her. 
The destined day arrived, and she was in the temple, not knowing what the priest was planning to do. They had a crystal that was going to focus light from the stars at the precise moment and burn her to a crisp. Her companion ended up saving her, pushing the priest into the light at the last moment. There were some sort of special effects, showing his flesh burning off until just his skeleton was left. The temple started shaking and the woman and her friend got out of there. The last scene was the huge gold statue splitting in two lengthwise and coming tumbling down, just as the protagonists made their getaway. 
I was maybe six years old when I saw this, and the scene with the priest burning up was terrifying to young me. It was not a children's show/movie (and my parents must not have been paying attention, or else I wouldn't have been permitted to watch it). I had nightmares about it. That is why this is still lodged in my memory 30-some years later. If anyone could help identify it, I'd be very grateful!
Edit: Yellow Hair and the Fortress of Gold (1984 movie) has some elements in common, but that's not it. 

Based on the last sentence, I deduce that you were six years old sometime in the 80's?

Yes indeed, I was six (or thereabouts) in the 1980s when I saw this. If it was a movie shown on TV, it could have been an older movie produced any time before the mid 1980s.
